# Table view is not refreshing on real device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell, row-height

I have a problem with a table view.

When I selected row, my height of cell is changing and display some information. If I select a second time, it's closing.

Works like a charm on simulator, but on real device, first part work fine, but when I want close it, he is executing the code but probably not refreshing tableView, because my information stay displayed.

Another problem for real device: my views is not appear.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


        return 4;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row ==1 &&show == YES) {
        return 50 + descLabel;

    }else if (indexPath.row == 2 && show2 == YES){

        return caracLabel;
    }

    {
    return 50;
    }
}




  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        NSString *cellID = @"detailCell";
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cellID = @"detailCell1";
                break;

            case 1:
                cellID = @"detailCell2";

                break;
            case 2:
                cellID = @"detailCell3";
                break;
            case 3:
                cellID = @"detailCell4";


            default:
                break;
        }

        detailCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];


        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.label.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

        if (indexPath.row == 1) {

            if (show == NO) {
                cell.labelDef.hidden =YES;


            }
            }



        return cell;


    }



 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        if (indexPath.row==1) {
        if (show == NO ) {

            detailCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detailCell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            show=YES;
            cell.label.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
            cell.labelDef.text=[self.desc objectAtIndex:pos];
            cell.labelDef.sizeToFit;
            cell.imageButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Play_Symbol_copie_5@3x.png"];
            cell.labelDef.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, cell.labelDef.frame.size.width, cell.labelDef.frame.size.height);
            cell.labelDef.hidden = NO;
            UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, cell.frame.size.width, cell.labelDef.frame.size.height)];
            [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:view];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.labelDef];
            descLabel = cell.labelDef.frame.size.height ;
    //        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

            [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                        animated:NO
                                  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

            [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


        }else{

            detailCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detailCell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            show= NO;
            cell.label.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
            cell.imageButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Play_Symbol_copie_2@3x.png"];
            cell.labelDef.hidden = YES;
    //        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

            [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                        animated:NO
                                  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

            [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
            }
        }else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            if ( show2 == NO) {
                detailCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detailCell3"forIndexPath:indexPath];
                show2=YES;
                cell.label.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                cell.image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
                cell.imageButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Play_Symbol_copie_5@3x.png"];
                NSArray *firstWords = [[self.carac objectAtIndex:pos] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
                UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, cell.frame.size.width  , 100)];
                [view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:246/256.0 green:245/256.0 blue:241/256.0 alpha:1]];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:view1];

                caracLabel = 50;
                for (int i = 0; i <firstWords.count; i++) {
                        NSArray *array = [[firstWords objectAtIndex:i]componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

                        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, caracLabel, 90, 20)];

                        label.text = [array objectAtIndex:0];
                        label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:150/256.0 green:150/256.0 blue:150/256.0 alpha:1];
                        label.numberOfLines = 0;
                        [label sizeToFit];

                        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

                        UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(110, caracLabel, 205, 20)];

                        label1.text = [array objectAtIndex:1];
                        label1.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:150/256.0 green:150/256.0 blue:150/256.0 alpha:1];
                        label1.numberOfLines = 0;
                        [label1 sizeToFit];

                        caracLabel = caracLabel + label1.frame.size.height;
                    if (i != firstWords.count - 1) {

                    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, caracLabel, cell.frame.size.width, 1)];
                    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                    caracLabel =caracLabel+2;
                        [cell.contentView addSubview:view];
                    }
                        [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];

                }

                UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 50, 1, caracLabel - 50)];
                [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:view];
                view1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, cell.frame.size.width, caracLabel-50);

    //            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
                [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]]
                                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

                [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                            animated:NO
                                      scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

                [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
            } else {
                detailCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detailCell3"forIndexPath:indexPath];
                show2= NO;
                cell.label.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                cell.image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
                cell.imageButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Play_Symbol_copie_2@3x.png"];

    //            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
                [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]]
                                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

                [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                            animated:NO
                                      scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

                [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
            }
        }else
        if (indexPath.row == 3){
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.wiki objectAtIndex:pos]]];
            UIWebView *video = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - +50)];
            [video loadRequest:request];
            video.delegate=self;
            showWeb = YES;
            UIActivityIndicatorView *actInd=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
            actInd.color=[UIColor blackColor];
            [actInd setCenter:self.view.center];
            self.activityIndicator=actInd;
            [self.view addSubview:video];

            [video addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
        }

    }
```

This is how looking/work on simulator : 
closed- [image: closed]

description-[image: description]

caracteristics- [image: caracteristics]

And this is how works for real device:
description-[image]

caracteristics-[image]

closed-[image] 
and [image]

I don't know if that is problem, but row is changing colour after i press first time in real device. Why? Any ideas?

Comment: I guess this is happening when you scroll?

Comment: No. My row just no closing.. :(

Comment: Don`t enable scroll function and try it

Comment: If i disable scroll function, i can't see information about description and carac.

Answer (score 0):

If everything working well in simulator but not in Device then check "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier"/"CellID" values because simulator is not case sensitive, but device is case sensitive.

It might be not find out your cell ID so it happen, I'm not sure about it but just check once.